# Union of infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \cup_{i \ge 1} A_i$, $i = 1, 2, \cdots$. This is union of countably infinite sets.

Also, $A_i \subsetneq B$ for all $i$, i.e. for every $A_i$, there exists at least one element in $B$ that is not in $A_i$.

It is also the case that $A_{i-1} \subsetneq A_{i}$ for all $i > 1$.

Then is it true that $A \subsetneq B$?

Intuitively, it seems true because for every $A_i$, I can point to an element that is in $B$ but not in $A_i$. However, it is not clear to me what happens after you take union of countably infinite sets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Take $A_i = \{ 1,2,...,i \} \subset B = \mathbb{N}$.

However, $A = \cup_i A_i = B$.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed such a simple example. Thanks.

Comment: Infinities are always tricky.

Comment: Doesn't need to be infinite.  A_1 = {0} A_2 = {1} B = {0,1} are finite and also is a counter example.

Comment: @fleablood It does need to be infinite. Your two $A_i$ don't satisfy $A_1\subsetneq A_2$. PS I now see that this requirement was added later.

Comment: @BrianO That requirement wasn't specified at the time I wrote the comment.  The OP didn't think it was relevant so s/he left it out.

Comment: @fleablood "Oh, right, just one more thing..." Argh :)

Comment: @BrianO It honestly slipped out of my mind. In the example I was thinking about, it was so much implicit, that I never thought of it explicitly until fleablood came up with a finite example.

Comment: I first assumed you meant nested infinite as that's the classic example (where nested intervals are basically equivalent to lim n = infinity) but as I typed my answer I realize it hadn't been stated and that a finite counter-example is possible.

Answer (score 3):

" i.e. there exists at least one element in B that is not in Ai for every Ai."

Not quite.  The element of $B$ that is not in $A_i$ could be an entirely different b that is not in $A_j$.  In fact you don't even need infinite sets.

Let $A_1 = \{1,3,5\}; A_2 = \{2, 4, 6\}; B = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. $A = A_1 \cup A_2$, $A_i \subsetneq B$ but $A = B$

=====

With the extra condition $A_i \subset A_{i-1}$ the answer is not so trivial but again the elusive element that isn't in $A_i$ can keep slipping away.

$A_i = (0, i) \subsetneq (0, \infty)$ so $A = \cup_{i} A_i = (0, \infty)$.

Let $b_i \notin A_i$ but $b \in (0, \infty)$ there is some $A_j; j > i$ that $b \in A_j$.  And then the $b_2$ that isn't in $A_j$ is in some further $A_k$ and so on.

There is no *one* element that is not in *all*.  Just for every $A_i$ there is *some* element not in it and for $A_j$ there is *another*.

Comment: Oops, there's a confusion of parantheses here. I meant: "for every $A_i$, there is at least one element which is in $B$, but not in that $A_i$", which is just restating that $A_i \subsetneq B$ (along with condition of subset-ness).

Comment: **Ignore my previous comment**. Oh, I see what you mean. I forgot to add mention the condition that $A_i \subset A_{i-1}$, which didn't seem relevant to me at that point. Now that you mention this example of finite sets, I realize that I should have added that condition so that the question is nontrivial only for countably infinite sets.

Comment: Very relevant condition.  You should add it to the OP.

Comment: Yes, it's just that in the example I had in mind I was implicitly assuming it. Fortunately the example in the other answer had that condition too. Thanks anyway for your input.

Comment: Your new example is similar to the answer I accepted. Indeed I agree with your statement now that "There is no *one* element that is not in *all*. Just for every $A_i$ there is *some* element not in it and for $A_j$ there is *another*.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am extremely confused, the assumption $A_i \subset A_{i-1}$ implies that, for example, $A_4$ is a subset of $A_3$. Then clearly, the principle of induction can be used to show that $\forall i, A_i \subset A_1,$ then $A=\cup_i A_i = A_1.$ Since by assumption $A_1 \subsetneq B$, we have $A\subsetneq B$.

If the assumption was actually that each subsequent set in the sequence contains the previous, then the other answers show that in fact it is possible to have $A=B$.

Comment: Typos, typos. Guess today's my bad day. You're correct, I meant that every set contains the previous.